# Using traco but the column is not translating in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, traco

My rails app was using translatable_column to load the config/locales/he-IL.yml content to its own column in a table's column.

the rails app is built with 3.0.19 and ruby 1.8.7, I installed traco gem "traco", "~> 1.0.0" 
I am not sure which traco version is compatible with 1.8.7. but I know its good with activerecord>3.

```
  create_table "statements", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "name_en_us"
    t.integer  "study_phase_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "position",                      :default => 1, :null => false
    t.text     "name_zh_cn"
    t.text     "name_de_de"
    t.text     "name_ja_jp"
    t.text     "name_es_es",     :limit => 255
    t.text     "name_it_it",     :limit => 255
    t.text     "name_ar_iq",     :limit => 255
    t.text     "name_et_ee",     :limit => 255
    t.text     "name_da_dk",     :limit => 255
    t.text     "name_en_ca"
    t.text     "name_en_au"
    t.text     "name_en_gb"
    t.string   "name_nl_nl"
    t.text     "name_en_sg"
    t.text     "name_sk_sk",     :limit => 255
    t.text     "name_cs_cz",     :limit => 255
    t.text     "name_ru_ru",     :limit => 255
    t.string   "name_ko_kr"
    t.string   "name_pl_pl"
    t.text     "name_fr_fr"
    t.string   "name_he_il"
  end
```

There are a lot of statements in the he-IL.yml file in config/locales

in my statement.rb model I have

```
translates :name
```

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. If you run this in a terminal, what happens? `s = Statement.new; I18n.locale = "en-US"; s.name = "My US name"; puts s.name` But I'm not sure any version of Traco works with Ruby 1.8. We dropped support for Ruby 1.8 in commit 9cf14177aa13e6c46f618f61c5b350b3dda6627d because there was some dependency issue with Active Support, perhaps introduced by a new release on their part, and we didn't want to spend time on supporting an end-of-lifed Ruby. Since it's a dependency error, I'm afraid you will likely see it with any version of Traco.

Comment: @HenrikN thanks the app was built 3 years ago with translatable_column, I have switched back to it. Its built with 1.8.7.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more, but glad you got it solved!

Comment: @HenrikN I ended up running a lot of sql queries to insert the data into the table's column